# link group of the trivial $n$ component link

Tags: knot-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Currently I am reading Milnor's paper "Link Groups". In the paper he defines the link group, for every $n$ component link $L$, as a certain quotient of the fundamental group $\pi_1 (S^3 \setminus L)$. On wikipedia in the article titled "link group" one can read that for trivial links this link group is isomorphic to the free group. However I think that this is impossible because the normal closure of the group generated by every meridian is abelian. So are the link groups of the trivial links free?

Comment: Presumably the term "link group" is being used in different ways. 
Typically it just means $\pi_1(S^3\setminus L)$, and for the trivial link this is free on the meridians.  I don't recall Milnor's definition, but if he is taking a quotient, his "link group" means something different.

Comment: Indeed, read the wikipedia article and the mathscinet review of Milnor's paper with more care and you will see that they are using the term "link group" in two different ways.

Comment: Milnor's link group is not the same as $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus L)$, but nonetheless the article and the review use the term differently.

Comment: Milnor's link group is invariant under "link homotopy", which allows strands to pass through themselves but not through other strands (this isn't obvious -- it's one of the main theorems of his paper).  In particular, under Milnor's definition the group of any knot is $\mathbb{Z}$ (since there are no other strands to get in the way of making the knot trivial).  This is very different from the fundamental group of the link complement.

Comment: Today I realized that the term link group means something else in both articles. Thanks for your comments anyway.