# What's the Milnor's link group for the trivial knot in a lens space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 3-manifolds, fundamental-group, knot-link

For a link $L$ in a 3-manifold $Y$, Milnor's paper "Link Groups" https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01393902.pdf defined the link group as some quotient of $\pi_1(Y-L)$. If $L$ is the trivial knot (bounding a disk) in a lens space $Y=L(p,q)$, then $\pi_1(Y-L)\cong \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/p$. By definition, the link group is $(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/p)/[A]$, where $[A]$ is the commutator subgroup of ${\rm ker}(\pi_1(Y-L)\to \pi_1(Y)\cong \mathbb{Z}/p)$. Is there any explicit way to describe this link group? Especially, do we have $(\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/p)/[A]\cong \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/p$?

My question comes from the argument in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_group, where it is said that the link group for trivial links in $S^3$ is isomorphic to a free group. However, in this question [link group of the trivial $n$ component link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98269/link-group-of-the-trivial-n-component-link), it seems that this argument is wrong since different articles use different definitions of "link group". Can we calculate any example of the link group in Milnor's sense explicitly?